# NodeJS Crypto Fails to Verify Signature Created by Web Crypto API

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

I'm having troubles verifying signatures created by the Web Crypto API.

Here is the code I'm using to generate RSA keys in the browser:

```
let keys;

const generateKeys = async () => {
  const options = {
    name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
    modulusLength: 2048, 
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: { name: 'SHA-256' }, 
  };

  keys = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    options,
    false, // non-exportable (public key still exportable)
    ['sign', 'verify'],
  );
};
```

And to export the public key:

```
const exportPublicKey = async () => {    
  const publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('spki', keys.publicKey);

  let body = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(publicKey)));
  body = body.match(/.{1,64}/g).join('\n');

  return `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${body}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

  // Output:
  //
  // -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  // MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAx7J3SUG4sq/HSGIaGZWY
  // 8b26cfEpVFYHoDUDUORIJzA/fLE9aj+uOKpGUTSfW69rMm7DAOLDz05KaEJJSI5+
  // YbDPr2S82A2ByHHQt+Vu168sGz4noXTTSX2HIdVutaR/IJ0a5pNOa1vRR4MUW/ZO
  // YaRir3yC5YXgcFLwwQaifNZ3lZ7WndbYEjTGOcieQQ81IUP2221PZCJI52S95nYm
  // VfslsLiPhOFH7XhGSqelGYDi0cKyl0p6dKvYxFswfKKLTuWnu2BEFLjVq4S5Y9Ob
  // SGm0KL/8g7pAqjac2sMzzhHtxZ+7k8tynzAf4slJJhHMm5U4DcSelTe5zOkprCJg
  // muyv0H1Acb3tfXsBwfURjiE0cvSMhfum5I5epF+f139tsr1zNF24F2WgvEZZbXcG
  // g1LveGCJ/0BY0pzE71DU2SYiUhl+HGDv2u32vJO80jCDf2lu7izEt544a+XE+2X0
  // zVpwjNQGa2Nd4ApGosa1fbcS5MsEdbyrjMf80SAmOeb9g3y5Zt2MY7M0Njxbvmmd
  // mF20PkklpH0L01lhg2AGma4o4ojolYHzDoM5a531xTw1fZIdgbSTowz0SlAHAKD3
  // c2KCCsKlBbFcqy4q7yNX63SqmI3sNA3kTH9CQJdBloRvV103Le9C0iY8CAWQmow5
  // N/sDJUabgOMqe9yopSjb7LUCAwEAAQ==
  // -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
};
```

To sign a message:

```
const generateHash = async (message) => {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const buffer = encoder.encode(message);

  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer);
  return digest;
};

const signMessage = async (message) => {
  const { privateKey } = keys;
  const digest = await generateHash(message);
  const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign('RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', privateKey, digest);
  return signature;
};
```

To verify the message in browser:

```
const verifyMessage = async (signature, message) => {
  const { publicKey } = keys;
  const digest = await generateHash(message);
  const result = await window.crypto.subtle.verify('RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', publicKey, signature, digest);
  return result;
};
```

When the keys are created, the public key is exported and sent to the server.  Later:

```
const message = 'test';
const signature = await signMessage(message);
await verifyMessage(signature, message); // true

sendToServer(message, bufferToHex(signature));
```

Since the signature is an ArrayBuffer, I convert it to hex with the following code:

```
const bufferToHex = input => [...new Uint8Array(input)]
  .map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
```

On the server (NodeJS 8.11.0):

```
const publicKey = getPublicKey(userId);

const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verifier.update(message, 'utf-8');

const sigBuf = Buffer.from(signature, 'hex');
verifier.verify(publicKey, sigBuf); // false
```

I've been chasing down this issue for days and just cannot seem to figure it out.  I've tried both `RSA-SHA256` and `sha256WithRSAEncryption` for verification to no avail.  Furthermore, no errors are being thrown.  Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't fully understand why this is the case, but to solve the issue I needed to convert the SHA hash from an ArrayBuffer into a hex string, then read back into an array buffer using TextEncoder.

```
const generateHash = async (message) => {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const buffer = encoder.encode(message);

  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer);

  // Convert to hex string
  return [...new Uint8Array(digest)]
    .map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');;
};
```

Then when signing:

```
const signMessage = async (message) => {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const { privateKey } = keys;
  const digest = await generateHash(message);
  const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign('RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', privateKey, encoder.encode(digest));
  return signature;
};
```

The signature no longer verifies on the client but it verifies in node.  ‍♂️

Comment: I disagree with this as the correct answer. The hashing is redundant since the hashing is done internally to the signature algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are signing the hash of hash of your input when you should actually be signing hash of your input. SubtleCrypto internally hashes the input. There is no need for you to provide hashed input. Since you provided hashed input as an argument, SubtleCrypto hashed it again and then signed it which led to mismatch of signatures.

Comment: Very insightful!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to note that both `crypto` and `crypto.subtle` hash the message before signing, so hashing separately is not necessary.

Assuming you were able to create and load your keys properly, your code should look like this.

### Browser

```js
const message = 'hello'
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
const algorithmParameters = { name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5' }
const signatureBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
  algorithmParameters,
  privateKey,
  encoder.encode(message)
)
const base64Signature = window.btoa(
  String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(signatureBytes))
)
console.log(base64Signature)
// TiJZTTihhUYAIlOm2PpnvJa/+15WOX2U0iKJ2LXsLecvohhRIWnwFfdHy4ci10mcv/UQgf2+bFf9lfFZUlPPdzckBNfXIqAjafM8XquJiw/t1v+pEGtJpaGASlzuWuL37gp3k8ux3l6zBKKbBVPPASkHVhz37uY1AXeMblfRbFE=
```

### Node

This implementation is using `crypto`, but you could use the `crypto.subtle` to be more similar to the browser javascript syntax

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')

const message = 'hello'
const base64Signature = 'TiJZTTihhUYAIlOm2PpnvJa/+15WOX2U0iKJ2LXsLecvohhRIWnwFfdHy4ci10mcv/UQgf2+bFf9lfFZUlPPdzckBNfXIqAjafM8XquJiw/t1v+pEGtJpaGASlzuWuL37gp3k8ux3l6zBKKbBVPPASkHVhz37uY1AXeMblfRbFE='
const hashingAlgorithm = 'rsa-sha256'
const doesVerify = crypto.verify(
  hashingAlgorithm,
  Buffer.from(message),
  { key: publicKey },
  Buffer.from(base64Signature, 'base64')
);
console.log(doesVerify)
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but it might just be easier to use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@peculiar/webcrypto so your code on client and server is consistent while addressing this problem at the same time.